# Show that the Hausdorff topology is unique in a finite set $X$

Tags: general-topology

It's these type of questions that I don't know what approach to even take. Which is stressful in an exam condition. My first thought was, well, why not assume there are at least two different topologies that are Hausdorff on $X$?

> Say $\tau_1,\tau_2$ are distinct topologies on $X$ with the Hausdorff property. Say we pick some distinct $x,y \in X$ such that $\exists U_1,V_1 \in \tau_1$ that are open and disjoint, by Hausdorffness. We pick $x,y$ so that $U_1$ or $V_1$ is not open in $X$ with $\tau_2$. We can find such $x,y$ since we assume $\tau_1,\tau_2$ are different topologies therefore at least one subset in $X$ considered open in one is not in the other.
>
> By Hausdorffness of $\tau_2$ we can also find open disjoint sets $U_2,V_2 \in \tau_2$ such that $x \in U_2$ and $y \in V_2$.

Here's where I start running out of ideas

> Perhaps take the intersection? $U_1 \cap U_2 \neq \phi$...$V_1 \cap V_2 \neq \phi$.

Then it stops. No idea what and how these will help me.

At this point I am not sure if my approach was utterly pointless in the first place assuming two distinct Hausdorff topologies...or I'm kind of in the right direction but not seeing what properties to look at?

I am trying to look for some contradiction but well, so far, nothing seems to be out of control, everything seems fine to have at least two different Hausdorff topologies on a finite set...so, why not? Can someone prove this...?

Comment: Try showing that for each $x\in X$, $\{x\}$ is open if $X$ is Hausdorff and $X$ is finite.

Comment: Let $x_0,x_1, \dots, x_n$ be the points. There is an open set $U_1$ that contains $x_0$ but not $x_1$. There is an open set that $U_2$ that contains $x_0$ but not $x_2$. And so on. The intersection of the $U_i$ is $\{x_0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that being Hausdorff is an "increasing property" (that means if $\mathcal{T}'\subseteq \mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$ is Hausdorff, then $\mathcal{T}$ is Hausdorff), you know that the only possible topology is the discrete topology. Now your goal is just to show that any Hausdorff topology on a finite set is discrete.

Since $\{x\}$ is closed $\forall x\in X$, you have that $\bigcup_{x\not = x_0} \{x\} = X-\{x_0\}$ is closed since it's a finite union. Hence, $\{x_0\}$ is open. $x_0$ is an arbitrary point in $X$, so your topology has to be the discrete topology.

Here, you should think that, since your set $X$ is finite, there is something to do with the intersection of a lot of open sets in $X$ (or equivalently, the union of a lot of closed sets in $X$).

Comment: @JohnTrail Oh yeah right, it's the other way around, I corrected it. I wanted to say: adding new sets to your topology will keep the property to be Hausdorff

Comment: Oh, right thanks, I'll read and work through again and come back if I still have doubts :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0\in X$; for each $x\in X$, $x\ne x_0$, there is an open neighborhood $V_x$ of $x$ that doesn't contain $x$. Since $X$ is finite,
$$
\bigcap_{\substack{x\in X\\x\ne x_0}}V_x
$$
is an open set containing $x_0$ and no other element of $X$. So $\{x_0\}$ is open. As $x_0$ is arbitrary, you're done.

Note that just the $T_1$ property has been used.